# I want to extract the games only

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I want to extract the games only

Code

```
private void loadApps(){
    manager = getPackageManager();
    apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    i.setType("Games");
    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
        AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
        app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
        app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
        apps.add(app);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I've never heard of `Games` as mime type, which is what [`setType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29) is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There's no distinction between "apps" and "games".

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher There's no distinction between "apps" and "games".